# TYPO3 references

Tags: content-management-system, typo3

I'm working recently on many TYPO3 Projects and I'd like to have a good tutorial/reference to work my way up. I'm looking for something like Agile Web Development with Rails but for TYPO3 if you like. The documentation of TYPO3 is good but not incredible so I was wondering if there was a better option out there.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

For extension development with **Extbase** and **Fluid**:

- Michael Schams: *[TYPO3 Extbase: Modern Extension Development for TYPO3 CMS with Extbase & Fluid](https://www.extbase-book.org/)* (2019, third edition, TYPO3 9)

For developing a **sitepackage** extension:

- Online: [TYPO3 Sitepackage Tutorial](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/SitePackageTutorial/) (official TYPO3 documentation)

For understanding the TYPO3 **extension architecture**:

- Online: [TYPO3 Explained: Extension Architecture](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/CoreApiReference/ExtensionArchitecture/Index.html) (official TYPO3 documentation)

For looking up specific things:

- Online: [TYPO3 Explained: API Overview](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/CoreApiReference/ApiOverview/Index.html) (official documentation)

In general: It depends on what you plan to do, so ask for specific recommendations on Slack:

1. [register](https://my.typo3.org/about-mytypo3org/slack/)
2. Go to https://typo3.slack.com
3. Join channel #typo3-cms
4. Ask your question.

Also, check out these resources:

Videos

- [Official TYPO3 YouTube channel](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCwpl8LY9Tr3PB26Kk2FYW_w)

Blogs

- [usetypo3](https://usetypo3.com/), for example check out [Good practices in extensions](https://usetypo3.com/good-practices-in-extensions.html)
- [TYPO3 Worx](https://typo3worx.eu/)
- see links to more blogs on https://typo3worx.eu page ...

---

## Outdated

In general: If you use a very old book, make sure it still applies to your version of TYPO3. If in doubt, ask on Slack: #typo3-cms (see above).

These books were recommended in original post:

- Michael Peacock: *[Building Websites with TYPO3](https://www.packtpub.com/beginning-typo3/book)* (Packt, 2007)
- Rene Fritz: *[TYPO3: Enterprise Content Management](http://typo3book.packtpub.com/)* (Packt, 2005)
- Daniel Koch: *[Mastering TypoScript](https://www.packtpub.com/master-typoscript-typo3/book)* (Packt, 2006)

The mailing lists still exists but there is very little activity. Use Slack oder StackOverflow to ask questions.

older text: *"Generally speaking, the best resource for learning TYPO3 outside the documentation is probably [the TYPO3 mailing lists](http://lists.typo3.org/cgi-bin/mailman/listinfo); I often find answers to questions just by searching the archives. TYPO3-English is for English-speaking general users; TYPO3-dev is for extension developers and those who want to hack on TYPO3 itself."*

Comment: I bought a couple of the Packt books. Among the english-language books Dmitry Dulepovs TYPO3: "Extension Development" has been of greatest value to me so far. Osipovs "Multimedia Cookbook" is also very inspiring. If you read German, you should visit amazon.de, where you'll find quite a lot of books, with O'Reillys "Praxiswissen TYPO3" and "TYPO3 Kochbuch" being the ones most used in my bookshelf (or, rather, on my desk).

Comment: This answer may have been good at some point but now, it is seriously outdated. Mailing lists? Not really being used anymore. Better to ask this question directly on Slack: https://my.typo3.org/about-mytypo3org/slack/ #typo3-cms. The first three books are really, really old. The book listed by Amazon should be ok, but it's for TYPO3 7. TYPO3 9 is now latest LTS.

Answer (score 6):

I would advice also of Patrick Lobacher "Certified TYPO3 Integrator" (English edition, e-book-version).

There are lots of examples with detailed explications, and this book will help a lot, if You would like to pass TYPO3 certification.

https://www.opensourcepress.de/index.php?26&tt_products=294

Answer (score 5):

Agree with jalefkowit - the Packt books are an excellent reference. I use my copy of Typo3 Enterprise Contente Management regularly. The mailing list is truly staggering in terms of what's in there. You can find answers to most difficulties in there somewhere.

A key thing I've found is spending time getting to know the api well. A good technique is to look for an extension that does something similar to what you want and then pull it apart to find which api calls it makes. You can then use the api browser to find out how it links to other objects - see api. typo3.org

Also very useful in terms of general strategy are 
the English translations of the T3 magazine articles
typo3.org/ documentation/t3n-magazine/
working your way through the many excellent podcasts
typo3.org/ podcasts/kasper
Dimitry Deulpov's blog has some brilliant insights
dmitry-dulepov.com/ category/typo3.html

Good luck - sorry for weird links - only allowed 1 link as a newbie

Answer (score 1):

There are quite some video tutorial available on https://www.youtube.com/user/typo3/videos 
Each Friday a new video is published, so the channel is worth subscribing. On the same channel you will also find recordings from TYPO3 conferences where they go deeper into certain topics.

Answer (score 0):

In addition I would like to recommend the [TYPO3 Extbase/Fluid Cheat Sheet](http://www.lobacher.de/files/cs/ExtbaseFluidCheatSheet_3.02_pluswerk.pdf). It has been a great help to get an overview of all the most important classes, structures and viewhelpers in Extbase and Fluid, and also as a quick reference. It's a bit outdated by now, but still very useful.