# Resources for learning extension development for TYPO3?

Tags: typo3

I am looking for resources for a learning extension developer.

The online documentation for Extbase / Fluid is listed as outdated. What are good resources to get started?

Comment: Typo3 Extbase, Modern Extension Development for TYPO3 CMS with Extbase & Fluid by Michael Shams and Patrick Lobacher is what I used. It is for T3 7.x but still very relevant.

Comment: A similar question already exists: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3928662/typo3-references

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) "**TYPO3 Extbase**" available in [german](https://leanpub.com/typo3extbase), [english](https://leanpub.com/typo3extbase-en) and [italian](https://leanpub.com/typo3extbase-it), this book builds an extension from the start and touches all aspects ... here you will get your extension working in any case since you can follow the code-examples and adapt them to your use. *(as a bonus it explains the real difference between TYPO3 and other CMS'ses, I leave that for you to discover)*

[image]

2) of course the **official documentation**:
outstanding for extensions are [ExtbaseFluidBook](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/ExtbaseFluidBook/b-ExtbaseReference/Index.html) and [ExtensionArchitecture](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/CoreApiReference/ExtensionArchitecture/Introduction/Index.html) *(a bit hard on beginners since you need to be able to interpret and apply explanations, the Extbase book from point 1 gives a complete working code model)*

3) **Of course the resource you're on right now** and TYPO3 has a rich **slack channel** [to which you can subscribe](https://forger.typo3.com/slack)

Answer (score 2):

I think TYPO3 Docs for Extbase reference is the best documents for learning extbase extension for developers.

In this docs explain every topics in details with example for the extbase extension.

You can check this docs here [ExtbaseFluidBook](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/ExtbaseFluidBook/b-ExtbaseReference/Index.html) and [ExtensionArchitecture](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/CoreApiReference/ExtensionArchitecture/Index.html)

Answer (score 1):

The [TYPO3 Extbase Book](https://extbase-book.org/) by Schams (English) and Lobacher (German) is quite good.

As of April 2018, the "Extbase Guide" at [TYPO3 DOCS](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/ExtbaseGuide/) is outdated, does not seem to be maintained and contains errors.